# MySQL: Same my.cnf, 3x slower

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, my.cnf

I am moving a PHP/Drupal/MySQL website from a virtual to a dedicated server. Weirdly, the site is much slower on the dedicated server. I could narrow down that the difference is likely caused mostly by MySQL with the following test.

A file `test.sql` contains 50.000 lines of:

```
 SELECT id FROM foobar WHERE bar = 'baz';
```

(The query returns 0 lines.)

Now, `$ time cat test.sql | mysql` shows me

```
        virtual     dedicated
real    0m2.193s    0m7.322s
user    0m0.574s    0m2.600s
sys     0m0.440s    0m2.558s
```

So on the dedicated server, the query takes more than 3x longer. I also compared `my.cnf` from both servers, they are identical.

Is there anything else that could cause the difference?

BTW: The dedicated server comes with [this hardware](https://www.webtropia.com/de/server-mieten/hp-moonshot-rootserver/moonshot-details.html?pid=MoonshotS). Both servers run on Ubuntu 14.04.

`$ mysql --version` returns

- virtual `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.40, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3`
- dedicated `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.41, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3`

Answer (score 1):

Since foobar is an empty table, it's not a memory problem.

The dedicated CPU is incredibly wimpy. If you're coming from a decent cloud like AWS, I would bet it's CPU speed.

EDIT: http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Atom+S1260+%40+2.00GHz